# Determine if numpy subarrays overlap?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I'm doing image analysis and have all images as numpy arrays. I want to determine if two subarrays / bounding boxes overlap.

I have the xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax values of all boxes. How can one determine if parts of box 1 (or the entire box) overlaps with box 2.

[image: Bounding boxes]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've answered the main part of your question below - what is the condition for two boxes to overlap. However, to fully answer your question, we need a code example (so we can see what you mean by "don't seem to work as intended"). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more. Also, the question is clear enough without the image example, and is not specific to image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition for no overlap is

```
def no_overlap(box1,box2,count_edge=False):
    return any(no_overlap_1d(*z1,*z2,count_edge)
        for z1,z2 in zip(box1,box2))

def no_overlap_1d(min1,max1,min2,max2,count_edge=False):
    if count_edge:
        return min1>max2 or min2>max1
    else:
        return min1>=max2 or min2>=max1
```

box1 and box2 are lists of min,max pairs.

Examples:

```
no_overlap([[1,5],[1,4]],[[3,4],[2,3]])
# False
no_overlap([[1,5],[1,4]],[[3,4],[4,5]])
# True
no_overlap([[1,5],[1,4]],[[3,4],[4,5]],True)
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment above, we can't fully answer your question without an example of what you tried and what didn't work.

However, the main part of your question is what are the conditions for 
two 2d boxes to overlap - which are:

```
box_1_in_box_2 = ((x_max_2> x_min_1 >= x_min_2) or (x_max_2>= x_max_1 >x_min_2)) and ((y_max_2> y_min_1 >= y_min_2) or (y_max_2>= y_max_1 > y_min_2))

box_2_in_box_1 = ((x_max_1> x_min_2 >= x_min_1) or (x_max_1>= x_max_2 >x_min_1)) and ((y_max_1> y_min_2 >= y_min_1) or (y_max_1>= y_max_2 > y_min_1))

overlap = box_1_in_box_2 or box_2_in_box_1
```

Comment: Sorry for not asking properly I will add code next time. My question was mostly of logical origin. Your answer was all I needed. Many thanks.

Comment: This seems to fail in the simple case of the two boxes being equal @BBQuercus, Itamar Mushkin

Comment: @PaulPanzer you're right! I'll edit it to correctly include edges.

Comment: I hate to be annoying, but it still fails if box2 is completely inside box1.

Comment: No no, you're right again. I've written the 1-sided test, and now edited to the 2-sided one.

Comment: I think you have to do the two-sided-ness dimension by dimension; as it stands I think it still doesn't two boxes which form a "plus sign" (like box1: [[2,3],[1,4]]   box2: [[1,4],[2,3]]   format: [[ymin,ymax],[xmin,max]]